# Django UUIDField docs say can be serialised but migrations mark it `serialize=False`

Tags: django, serialization, database-migration, code-generation

What causes Django's `UUIDField` type to be marked `serialize=False`? How can I specify that it should be `True`?

The documentation for [database migrations, under “Serializing values”](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/migrations/#serializing-values), explicitly states that `uuid.UUID` instances can be serialised:

> Django can serialize the following:
> […]
> uuid.UUID instances

That sounds good to me. So I define a model with a UUIDField primary key:

```py
import uuid
from django.db import models

class Lorem(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(
        verbose_name='ID',
        default=uuid.uuid4,
        editable=False,
        serialize=True,
        primary_key=True)
    dolor = models.CharField([…])
```

Despite specifying `serialize=True` explicitly, the `makemigrations` management command produces this field, where all the arguments are the same except it has changed to `serialize=False`:

```py
    […]
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Lorem',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.UUIDField([…], primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('dolor', models.CharField([…])),
            ],
        )
    […]
```

What is causing the `makemigrations` command to insist that the UUIDField should not be serialized? How can I get it to **work the way the documentation for “Serializing values” describes, and `serialize=True`**?